# Rails 4: stubbing in a Capybara & Poltergeist integration test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

I'm having trouble testing a rather simple spec using Capybara & Poltergeist in a Rails 4 app.

The spec looks like this:

```
feature 'Creating user groups', :devise, js: true do
  let(:panel) { create(:panel) }
  let(:admin) { create(:user, :admin) }

  before do
    login_as(admin)
    visit admin_panel_user_groups_path(panel)
    click_link 'New user group'
  end

  context 'successfully' do
    it 'admin can create a new user group' do
      fill_in 'User group', with: 'Some group'
      click_button 'Save'

      expect(page).to have_content('Your user group has been saved correctly')
    end
  end
end
```

The spec ends up calling this `create` method, which returns a json response with `format.js` (which is why I run the above spec with `js: true`):

```
class Admin::UserGroupsController < AdminController
  respond_to :html, :json, :js, :csv
  before_action :set_panel

  def create
    respond_to do |format|
      @user_group = UserGroup.new(user_group_params.merge({panel_id: @panel.id}))
      if @user_group.save
        @user_group.refresh!
        format.js do
          render json: {
            responseType: 'modelSaved',
            object: @user_group
          }.to_json, status: 200
        end
      else
        format.js do
          render json: {
            responseType: 'error',
            object: @user_group
          }.to_json, status: 500
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

I've set up Poltergeist in my `rails_helper.rb` fie:

```
require 'capybara/poltergeist'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include Warden::Test::Helpers, type: :feature
  config.after(type: :feature) { Warden.test_reset! }
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
end
```

but I'm getting the following error message when I run the spec:

```
Failure/Error: visit admin_panel_user_groups_path(panel)
WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError:
Real HTTP connections are disabled. Unregistered request: GET http://127.0.0.1:54553/__identify__ with headers {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:get, "http://127.0.0.1:54553/__identify__").
with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'}).
to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})

registered request stubs:

stub_request(:get, "/http:\/\/maps.googleapis.com\/maps\/api\/geocode\/json?components=country:US|postal_code:\d+/")
stub_request(:get, "https://freegeoip.net/json/123.123.123.123").
with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'gzip;q=1.0,deflate;q=0.6,identity;q=0.3', 'User-Agent'=>'Ruby'})
```

I believe this is happening because external connections are not allowed in the specs (which is good). However, does it make sense to stub external requests in integration tests? Am I configuring Poltergeist incorrectly or thinking about this test incorrectly?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really shouldn't have WebMock enabled when running feature tests (it can't stub or block requests made by the "browser" you're using, PhantomJS,  anyway so it's not really protecting you from outgoing connections).  So you either need to allow connections when running feature tests

```
WebMock.allow_net_connect!
```

or at the very least allow connections to the AUT which in this case is being run on 127.0.0.1

```
WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm trying `WebMock.disable_net_connect!(allow_localhost: true)` with the spec but it fails on the same line (i.e. `visit admin_panel_user_groups_path(panel)`) with another error: `Capybara::Poltergeist::StatusFailError: Request to 'http://127.0.0.1:58164/en/admin/panels/p1/user_groups' failed to reach server, check DNS and/or server status - Timed out with no open resource requests`. I have a reCaptcha on the `sign_in` page but this should be disabled in test. I also have a geolocation check with the geocoder gem, but this should be bypassed if the user is an admin.

Comment: @DaniG2k That's a different issue/question, but it's probably timing out while your app is compiling assets.  You should be able to see if this is the case by looking at your `test.log` and seeing what requests have been made and how long they are taking to respond. You can try increasing the timeout in your driver registration - https://github.com/teampoltergeist/poltergeist#customization - or by precompiling the assets in the test environment.

Comment: Thanks, a combination of increasing the timeout and allowing localhost connections seems to have done the trick. Much appreciated!!